# Как реализовать все методы при наследовании интерфейса на C#

Tags: c#, наследование

Я только начал писать на c#. Объясните пожалуйста, с чем связана ошибка:
`KeyDoorToDoor` не реализует член интерфейса `IDoor.Open()`. И подскажите, как её исправить.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
interface IDoor
{
    void Open();

}//Интерфейс двери

class KeyDoorToDoor : IDoor
{
    KeyDoor door;
    public KeyDoorToDoor(KeyDoor d)
    {
        door = d;

        door.PutKey(); //вставляем ключ в дверь, чтобы открыть
        door.RotateKey(); //поворачиваем ключ, чтобы открыть дверь
        door.Open(); //Открываем
    }
  public void Open()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
} //Адаптер от PasDoor к IDoor
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `KeyDoorToDoor не реализует член интерфейса IDoor.Open()` а он его реализует разве? Или в чем вопрос? Если код не ваш - то вперед разбираться, что такое интерфейсы, можете начать [отсюда](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.9.php)

Comment: В строке class KeyDoorToDoor : IDoor''' выдает ошибку, указанную выше. При попытке его реализовать введя: 
``` public void Open()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
``` 
Прога запускается, но не полностью и также ругается на то, что метод не реализован.

Comment: Уберите весь лишний код из вопроса. Оставьте только интерфейс и ваш класс с вашими изменениями и ошибкой

Comment: `throw new NotImplementedException();` и бросает ошибку из скриншота

Comment: Почитайте, что такое исключения

Comment: `throw new NotImplementedException();` - это "заглушка", которую нужно заменить на реальный код, реализующий нужный вам функционал.

Comment: автор сменил проблему, пока редактировал вопрос. Изначально вопрос был про `Объясните пожалуйста, с чем связана ошибка: KeyDoorToDoor не реализует член интерфейса IDoor.Open()` , теперь на скрине совершенно другая проблема.

Comment: `using System` добавить для пользования исключения

Comment: @Dmitry, он был прописан, просто не показался почему-то

Comment: Чтобы отметить вопрос решенным, выберите наиболее полезный ответ и примите его, для этого нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напутали со скобочками. Попробуйте так:

```
interface IDoor
{
    void Open();

}//Интерфейс двери

class KeyDoorToDoor : IDoor
{
    KeyDoor door;
    public KeyDoorToDoor(KeyDoor d)
    {
        door = d;

        door.PutKey(); //вставляем ключ в дверь, чтобы открыть
        door.RotateKey(); //поворачиваем ключ, чтобы открыть дверь
        door.Open(); //Открываем
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

} //Адаптер от PasDoor к IDoor
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ту же самую ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: Быть того не может, добавил картинку в ответ где код компилируется без проблем.

Comment: Это вижла? Где получить il + native и tree? какие-то расширения?

Comment: @Kalmankantaja это https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: @Никита уберите `throw new NotImplementedException();` из кода и ошибка пропадет.

Comment: @tym32167  у меня ощущение что не прописан namespace для вызова данного исключения у автора вопроса. `using System`

Comment: @Dmitry у автора в вопросе на скрине код уже скопилирован и запущен, но вылетает exception который сам автор и создает.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, теперь ошибки нет.

Answer (score 1):

Реализуйте метод как то иначе, на данный момент он у вас сам и генерирует исключение. [Генерация исключений](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.31.php)

```
public void Open()
{
   // throw new NotImplementedException();
 
   Console.WriteLine("Открыли дверь");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё элементарно, вы фигурную скобку поставили не там:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас вышло так, что метод оказался вне класса.

Comment: Ту же самую ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: обновите вопрос скриншотом

Comment: Пожалуйста прикладывайте текстовую информацию текстом